# How can I make a border mesh with 2 pointsets that each have their own length

Tags: coordinates, polygon

So i need to create a border mesh from 2 different pointsets that have their own length. The "mesh" needs to be a list of polygons that are sorted clockwise, the polygons can contain any number of points.

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gz4B.png)

I used to do this by looping through the points in the outer set, and for each point I would connect it to the closest point of the inner set. After that I would make faces with 4 points out of the lines I made. This worked perfectly.
But now we run into the problem that the outer point set no longer has the same length as the inner set. So our current approach will no longer work.

if someone could help me in the right direction or with an example on how to achieve this that would be greatly appreciated